# I must forgo half the RAM, otherwise computer freezes, hardware issue suspected

Tags: memory, hardware-failure

I have 8GB of RAM. Debian reports seeing 7.8, Windows about the same.

A few months ago I installed Debian dual-boot on my Win7 home machine. At the time I thought it'd be a good idea to open up the case for cleaning. I'm pretty confident the Debian install didn't mess anything up but I'm mentioning it just in case.

My habit for the past few months is to inspect the System Monitor (or task manager on Windows) every time I boot the machine. If I see 7.8GB, I know that in about 10-30 minutes the computer will freeze (and if any audio happens to be playing it'll get stuck in a loop). As you can all imagine, a cold reboot is the only way out.

The boot-up process usually involves me looking at the screen to make sure it doesn't get stuck in the motherboard logo screen, or GOTO 1. These mis-boots started around the same time as the main problem I describe.

If I'm "lucky" on the next boot-up I'll see 3.9GB available. When this happens I know the system is in a good state and can run for days if needed. It's important to mention the problem is OS-independant. The only perceptable difference is that Debian audio gets stuck in a ~1s loop, while Windows has a much shorter (and thus more annoying) period.

I suspect some loose connections are at fault. A program tries to allocate on one chip, the chip fails, voila. The next restart is usually successful on the first try (because it's already warm and that somehow causes it to pre-fail??) but that might be a coincidence. I tried pushing the RAM chip all the way in, it won't go any further.

Okay, question:

- How can I pinpoint what the problem is?

The threads I've found so far involve doing some voodoo in msconfig but as I said my problem isn't OS-bound.

Comment: Does your bios have any kind of memory check utility?  As it really looks like one of the sticks is damaged.  Try running the machine with one stick, then the other.  I'm betting on one it will work fine, on the other you'll get the same issues.

Comment: Try to test your RAM with memtest: http://www.memtest.org/ and/or try swapping the RAM modules.